# How to make this JS to show next card instead of random cards?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm working on a Swipe card project using HTML, CSS and JS.

I took this JS code from codepen and I implemented it but the problem is the cards are randomizing. How to make it to be in sequence (not repeating)?

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ionic.contrib.ui.cards'])
  .directive('noScroll', function($document) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
        $document.on('touchmove', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        });
      }
    }
  })

  .controller('CardsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSwipeCardDelegate) {
    var cardTypes = [
      {title: '1'},
      {title: '2'},
      {title: '3'},
      {title: '4'},
      {title: '5'}
    ];

    $scope.cards = Array.prototype.slice.call(cardTypes, 0, 0);

    $scope.cardSwiped = function(index) {
      $scope.addCard();
    };

    $scope.cardDestroyed = function(index) {
      $scope.cards.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.addCard = function() {
      var newCard = cardTypes[
        Math.floor(Math.random() * cardTypes.length)
      ];
      newCard.id = Math.random();
      $scope.cards.push(angular.extend({}, newCard));
    }
  })

  .controller('CardCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSwipeCardDelegate) {
    $scope.goAway = function() {
      var card = $ionicSwipeCardDelegate.getSwipeableCard($scope);
      card.swipe();
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the following:

```js
$scope.cards = Array.prototype.slice.call(cardTypes, 0, 0);
```

Replacing it with:

```js
$scope.cards = cardTypes; // this keeps the series ordered as is defined
```

You may want to `.reverse()` cardTypes so the first item in the array is the first card (the cards are actually popped from the array, so the last item will be the first card if you don't reverse it):

```js
$scope.cards = cardTypes.reverse(); // reverse the array
```

An then it seems that new cards are randomly added after each Swipe:

```js
$scope.cardSwiped = function(index) {
  $scope.addCard();
};
```

Maybe you can comment the whole thing, or just the `$scope.addCard()` if it breaks the app.

Comment: Well, then I probably didn't understand your question, I've tried on the codepen you provided and it works as expected. (With my understanding of what you wanted to achieve).

Comment: Do you want to display the cards as a series and in the same order as they were defined? And then do you want the series to end after the last card was reached, or do you want to repeat the series?

Comment: Here is the [forked codepen](https://codepen.io/daformat/pen/qwBrzv?editors=0010)

Comment: You're welcome, another version based on @DMishra's answer and probably cleaner: [codepen](https://codepen.io/daformat/pen/XQWRbx?editors=0010). You should use this instead so the first 'Swipe down to show a new card' card is shown at the beginning instead of the end

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with your `$scope.addCard`
While getting a new card you are using Math.Random

**Correct way**-

```
    var cardCount = -1;//    
    $scope.addCard = function () {
        if (cardCount < cardTypes.length - 2) {
            cardCount++;//get the next card
        }
        else {
            alert("Reached last card");//last card reached
        }
        var newCard = cardTypes[cardCount];
        newCard.id = cardCount;
        $scope.cards.push(angular.extend({}, newCard));
    }
```

Comment: It breaks the app.

Comment: here is the link of Codepen I used. https://codepen.io/ionic/pen/skbxh?editors=0010

Comment: `cardCount > cardTypes.length - 2` should be `cardCount < cardTypes.length - 2`